# Unable to create a JiraRestClient

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to create a JiraRestClient using Basic authentication.

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
URI jiraServerUri = getJiraUri();
JiraRestClient restClient =  factory
 .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

However, I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.atlassian.fugue.Option.fold(Lcom/google/common/base/Supplier;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.proxy.ProxyConfigFactory.getProxyHost(ProxyConfigFactory.java:16)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.<init>(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:211)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.<init>(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:123)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.doCreate(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:68)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.create(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:63)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at com.jira.JiraClient.getJiraRestClient(JiraClient.java:37)
    at com.jira.JiraClient.getIssue(JiraClient.java:25)
    at com.jira.JiraClient.main(JiraClient.java:20)
```

It seems that some runtime dependency is missing. But not sure which one.

Here is the snippet from my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
        <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-m007</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of fugue compatible with JRJC 4.0.0is 2.6.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
    <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar error in version 5.2.0 and I was able to fix it using below dependency instead of using jira-rest-java-client-core directly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of a missing library. This is due to the version mismatch between fugue and jira-rest-java-client-core in your pom.

Looking briefly at the [source](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/fugue), Fugue expects JDK interface while rest library is providing guava one.

Try fixing version OR don't specify fugue at all. It should come as a transitive dependency.

Comment: I tried without fugue initially, got NoClassDefFoundError. Then I added the dependency. I will verify the versions. But I thought that the Guava interfaces are extending JDK interfaces and passing them shouldn't be a problem.